# python how to search a string, count values and group by in json

Tags: python, json, string, search, count

I have a python program calling an API that receives the result as below:

```
{
   "result": [
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "5"
       },           
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "5"
       },           
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "5"
       },           
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "3"
       },           
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "7"
       },           
       {
         "company" : "AUDI",
         "model" : "A3"
       },           
       {
         "company" : "AUDI",
         "model" : "A7"
       },           
]
}
```

Now my task is to identify the number of occurrences of elements from the list in JSON output and group them. The expected output should look like this:

```
{
   "BMW" :
       {
         "5series" : 3,
         "3series" : 1,
         "7series" : 1,
       },
   "AUDI" :
      {
         "A3" : 1,
         "A7" : 1,          
      },
  "MERCEDES":
      {
         "EClass" : 0,
         "SClass" : 0
     }
}
```

I need to find the "company" from list of elements. This will include names that may not be in JSON response sometimes, then the expected output should include that as 0. The "model" names (3,5,7,A3 etc..,) are fixed, so we know that's those are only ones that may or may not be in json api response.

For ex: The List has 3 company names in below code. - companyname = ["BMW,"AUDI","MERCEDES"] . However, sometimes, the JSON API response may not have one or more elements. In this case,  "MERCEDES" is missing, but the final output should include "MERCEDES" as well with value as 0.

Here is what i have tried so far:

````
def modelcount():
    companyname= ["BMW","AUDI","MERCEDES"]
    url = apiurl   

    #Send Request

    apiresponse = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
    data = apiresponse.json()

    print(len(data['result']))

    3series= 0
    5series= 0
    7series= 0
    A3=0
    A7=0
    EClass = 0
    SClass = 0
    modelcountjson = {}

    for name in companyname:

        for item in data['result']:
            models= {}
            if item['company'] == name:
                if item['model'] == 3:
                    3series = 3series + 1
                elif item['model'] == 5:
                    5series = 5series + 1
                elif item['model'] == 7:
                    7series = 7series + 1

                models['3series'] = 3series
                models['5series'] = 5series
                models['7series'] = 7series                           

#I still haven't written AUDI, MERCEDES above. This is where i feel i am writing inefficiently.

                   modelcountjson[name] = models

    return jsonify(modelcountjson)


```
````

As the number of models grow, I am worried of code getting redundant with many for loops and may cause performance overhead. I am looking for help on achieving the end result in most efficient way.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Could there be more companies or only those 3? How would the models of Mercedes look coming from the API. Do they need similar processing like the BMW?

Comment: Hi,
Currently there are only 3 companies and  it may grow depending on the need. For mercedes models it will be "ESeries" and "SSeries" and it will be same format as BMW and AUDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for a bit of a separation of code and config:

```
conf = {
    'BMW': {'format': '{}series', 'keys': ['3', '5', '7']},
    'AUDI': {'format': '{}', 'keys': ['A3', 'A7']},
    'MERCEDES': {'format': '{}Class', 'keys': ['E', 'S']},
}

def modelcount():
    # retrieve `data`
    # ...
    result = {
        k: {
            v['format'].format(key): 0 for key in v['keys']
        } for k, v in conf.items()
    }
    for car in data['result']:
        com = car['company']
        mod = car['model']
        key = conf[com]['format'].format(mod)
        result[com][key] += 1
    for com in result:
        result[com]['Total'] = sum(result[com].values())
    return result

>>> modelcount()
{'BMW': {'3series': 1, '5series': 3, '7series': 1}, 
 'AUDI': {'A3': 1, 'A7': 1}, 
 'MERCEDES': {'EClass': 0, 'SClass': 0}}
```

This way, for more companies and models, you will only have to touch the `conf`, not the code. The time complexity of this is `O(m+n)` with `m` the total number of distinct models and `n` the number of cars in the API response.

Comment: Thank you so much schwobaseggl for your quick response. Let me get back you on this.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Just wondering, how to sum these numbers to key "Total"? ex: {'BMW': { '3series': 1, '5series': 3, '7series': 1, 'Total': 5}, 
 'AUDI': {'A3': 1, 'A7': 1, 'Total': 2}, 
 'MERCEDES': {'EClass': 0, 'SClass': 0, 'Total' : 0}}

Answer (score 1):

A useful package for working directly with JSON-style dictionaries and lists is `toolz` (see [documentation](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#functoolz) for more details). This way you can concisely group the data and count occurrences of each model while handling potentially missing data separately:

```
from toolz import itertoolz

result = {
   "result": [
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "5"
       },
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "5"
       },
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "5"
       },
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "3"
       },
       {
         "company" : "BMW",
         "model" : "7"
       },
       {
         "company" : "AUDI",
         "model" : "A3"
       },
       {
         "company" : "AUDI",
         "model" : "A7"
       },
    ]
}

final_output = {}
grouped_result = itertoolz.groupby('company', result['result'])

if 'MERCEDES' not in grouped_result:
    final_output['MERCEDES'] = {
        'EClass': 0,
        'SClass': 0
    }

for key, value in grouped_result.items():
    models = itertoolz.pluck('model', value)
    final_output[key] = itertoolz.frequencies(models)
```

The output results in:

```
{'AUDI': {'A3': 1, 'A7': 1}, 'BMW': {'3': 1, '5': 3, '7': 1}, 'MERCEDES': {'EClass': 0, 'SClass': 0}}
```

Comment: Hello Madjazz, this is great too. Thanks a lot for your help.. i tried schwobaseggl answer as there is no dependency on extra library. But your solution is breeze :)